# How to configure Emacs' align-rules-list to line up =, -> and | in Haskell code?

Tags: emacs, alignment, elisp

I often write code that looks like the following:

```
data Tok =
  TokA String |
  TokS Char   |
  TokL String
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Tokenizer = Tokenizer { runTokenizer :: (Tok, Tokenizer) }

tokenize xs = Tokenizer $ go xs
  where
    psh []     = go xs
    psh (r:rs) = (TokS r, Tokenizer (psh rs))
    plg rs     = (TokL rs, Tokenizer (go xs))
    go (x:xs)  =
      case span (== '-') x of
        (_, "")    -> (TokA x, Tokenizer (go xs))
        ("-", rs)  -> psh rs
        ("--", rs) -> plg rs
        _          -> (TokA x, Tokenizer (go xs))
```

Note that the `|` symbols are lined up, the `->` symbols are lined up and the = symbols are lined up.

I've tried to use the Emacs `align` command but it doesn't work automatically, so I have to resort to using `align-regexp` and a lot of typing. I understand I can modify `align-rules-list` to somehow do detection and application of a specific rule automatically, but I have no idea how to modify the variable to do this. Can someone help me in the three cases above?